# Reservation Solution for RealEstate integrating with Joomla

Tags: joomla, payment

My client needs a Property (Just Land NO Houses) Reservation solution for their existing website (It runs in Joomla). I need some advice/Tips on what approach should I use. I'm looking for an Opensource solution that I can customize to my need.

The Scenario:

A buyer reserves a lot, A form appears gathers his details after that he/she pays for the reservation.

FrontEnd:

I need a form builder extension in Joomla that I could build custom form in gathering information (name, email, contact info, address...) from the buyer or the person who is reserving it. After I gather the info I need another extension that will handle the payment for reserving it. This is kinda shopping cart type approach, you see a product and the buy it. But would just need extra details.

Backend:

I can see all the details of the buyer from their name to the time they paid for a reservation.

Thanks!

P.S. I'm open to all Ideas. I'm not sure of this approach. Please let me know If you have some good Ideas or example.

Answer (score 0):

You have three approaches IMO:

1. Search for [joomla extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/) that provide [reservation features](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search/reservation);
2. "Adapt" a component from joomla extensions, and provide these modifications to the open source project itself;
3. Create your own component from scratch, inspired by other extension's source.

Sometimes the extensions have a "lite" and a "pro" version, and you may need to pay for them to have all features, so I think it's up to you to decide what it's worth in your case.